# Do body-parser json() and urlencoded() functions replace express json() and urlencoded() functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

The express framework comes with the express functions `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`.

We have the body-parser library, which appears to do the same functions.

My question is, does body-parser replace `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`?

Does it handle creating the `req.body` differently to the built in Express functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body-parser package existed as Express middlewere until Express 4.0.  At that point it was removed from the Express bundle, but people still relied on it.  So around 4.1 Express brought it back but integrated it into the framework.

So yes, it’s effectively a direct replacement as these functions are directly based on body-parser.  As such, they’re essentially synonymous.  The Express team actually maintains body-parser.

Comment: Thanks @bob I appreciate your replay. 

Does it make a difference functionally if I use body-parser over express.json() and express.urlencoded()?

Comment: No, it’s functionally the same.  Your requests will be built as you’re accustomed to.

Comment: Thanks Bob, your a champ for answering this for me.

Comment: Looking through the express source code, I found that express.json and express.urlencoded are effectively just wrappers for body-parser. So whether you use body parser or the express versions, it is the same fundamental source code.